# Simplest way to find any vector with a different direction

Tags: linear-algebra, vectormath

What is the simplest way to take an input vector, given as (x,y,z), and find some new vector with a different direction than it? Any direction will do, it just has to be a different direction than the input (other than exact opposite direction, which is trivial).

It seems like there should be a simple solution that does not involve branching, but I can't seem to find one, and after some though, I'm interested to know if there actually is one.

Comment: any vector that is not in the form of a*(x,y,z) will do

Comment: well, to be more specific, I want a way to find one of those vectors which is not in that form, by using some function of the input vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how simple this is, but assuming that (x,y,z) has length L (which is not 0) the vector below has length 1 and is at right angles to (x,y,z)

```
-y * (x + sign(x)*L) / (L*(L+|x|))
1 - y * y / (L*(L+|x|))
-y * z / (L*(L+|x|))
```

(here |x| is the absolute value of x and sign(x) is -1 if x<0, and 1 if x >= 0)

I derived this formula by computing the householder reflection ( eg  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation) that maps (x,y,z) to a multiple of (1,0,0) and then computing the image of (0,1,0) under this matrix; since the matrix is both orthogonal and symmetric this vector will be orthogonal to (x,y,z).

There is no continuous function (x,y,z) -> (x',y',z') (for (x,y,z) != (0,0,0)) such that (x',y',z') is never a multiple of (x,y,z); if there were you could remove from (x',y',z') its component in the (x,y,z) direction and so get a continuous map (x,y,z)->(x'',y'',z'') where (x'',y'',z'') is at right angles to (x,y,z), but by the [hairy ball theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem) you can't.

In the formula above the occurrence of the discontinuous sign function makes the formula discontinuous. Note that sign needn't involve a branch; in some languages there is a build in function to do it; in C you could use 2*(x>=0)-1.

Comment: Using sign is sort of still branching, but that is the sort of answer I was looking for, thanks. I did manage to find another even simpler answer: <x,y,z> => <z,-z,x+y>. The proof that they are different for all non-zero inputs using that transform is quite easy.

Comment: For (1,-1,0) you get (0,0,0).